# Can't launching a script from bspwmrc

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bspwm, lemonbar

I have a lemonbar script that I modified from a few other scripts. Here: https://hastebin.com/iduhutorec Config here: https://hastebin.com/ewohugidut

I moved it to `~/.local/bin/` as `lemon-script` (which is in my path), then I added this line to my bspwmrc:

```
# Launch bar
lemon-script &
```

However it does not launch. I can launch it from terminal as any other command just fine tho...

* this is how I added `~/.local/bin/` to my path (in my `.bashrc`):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"
```

* I found a dumb solution, I just added the path to the script, but I would like more if it worked without it, or at least a explanation why it is how it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `bspwmrc` doesn't use `bash` to execute its contents, so it doesn't execute `.bashrc`. You can do `sudo vim /etc/profile`. It will have a section like:

```
appendpath '/usr/local/sbin'
appendpath '/usr/local/bin'
appendpath '/usr/bin'
unset -f appendpath

export PATH
```

Between the line beginning with `unset` and the last line beginning with `appendpath`, add `appendpath '/home/$your_user_name/.local/bin'`. See that there is no leading slash after `bin`.

Then I am quite sure you will have to restart. Try executing the script after that.

Comment: That was it thanks!